# Tell Fragment which XML to Inflate

Tags: android, xml, android-3.0-honeycomb, android-fragments, inflate

I start with a home fragment that opens either a listFragment(Al) or I can choose a normal Fragment(Jim). If my new Fragment(Bob) is called from the listFragment(Al), I want Fragment(Bob) to call XML A. If Fragment(Bob) is called from Fragment(Jim) I want Fragment(Bob) to inflate XML B. How do I pass a value from listFragment(Al) and Fragment(Jim) that can be checked in the onCreateView of Fragment(Bob) so that Fragment(Bob) knows which XML to inflate?

Hope that all makes sense.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use get/set arguments:
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Fragment.html#getArguments()

[edit]

So when you create Fragment Bob from Fragment Jim you could do something like this:

```
Bob b = Bob.newInstance();
Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
bundle.put("resourceId", R.id.XMLB);
b.setArguemnts(bundle);
```

or you could even in the newInstance method take in the resourceId

```
Bob b = new Bob.newInstance(R.id.XMLB);
```

Comment: I figure thats what I need to use, the problem is I can't make anything out of that.

Comment: Ok. So once I have that set how does Bob know to use that XML when inflating the view?

Comment: Ya. Sorry. There you go. Thanks